# Syntax Error: Inserting Equations VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a syntax error for the following bolded code.

```
' Headline Length Equation

Do

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N.A"

End If

**Columns("O:O").Formula = "=IF(LEN(TRIM(A2))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(A2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")+1)"**

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1))
```

Comment: Final Code:

    Sheets("Raw Data").Select
    Range("R2:R" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Formula = "=IF(LEN(TRIM(A2))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(A2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"" "", """"))+1)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just double up the quotes

```
"=IF(LEN(TRIM(A2))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(A2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"" "",""""))+1)"
```

+

[HERE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/count-the-number-of-words-in-a-cell-or-range-HA001034625.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @mehow. While the formula does run, all of the values in my workbook are showing up as the '#Value' error. I am not sure why this formula is not able to count the number of words available. Do you have any ideas on why this may be happening?

Comment: There is an error in the function I think... Missing a `)` at the end.